# sqllite error "joins not supported"

Tags: linq, sqlite, xamarin.forms

i have the following queries

```
 List<FullSthotram> sthotraas = (from m in db.Table<MSthotram>()
                                                   join q in db.Table<MUserSthotram>() on m.SthotraID equals q.SthotramID into mq
                                                   from r in mq.DefaultIfEmpty(new MUserSthotram())
                                                   join n in db.Table<MLanguage>() on m.LanguageID equals n.LanguageID
                                                   join o in db.Table<MAuthor>() on m.AuthorID equals o.AuthorID
                                                   join p in db.Table<MGod>() on m.GodID equals p.GodID
                                                   where m.IsActive == true && (m.SthotraID == SthotramID)
                                                   select new FullSthotram()
                                                   {
                                                       Author = o.Name,
                                                       God = p.Name,
                                                       Name = m.Name,
                                                       Language = n.Name,
                                                       SthotraID = m.SthotraID,
                                                       SthotramData = m.SthotramData,
                                                       NativeName = m.NativeName
                                                   }).ToList();
```

works well retrieves data

```
 List<FullSthotram> sthotraas = (from m in db.Table<MSthotram>()
                                                   join n in db.Table<MLanguage>() on m.LanguageID equals n.LanguageID
                                                   join o in db.Table<MAuthor>() on m.AuthorID equals o.AuthorID
                                                   join p in db.Table<MGod>() on m.GodID equals p.GodID
                                                   where m.IsActive == true && (m.SthotraID == SthotramID)
                                                   select new FullSthotram()
                                                   {
                                                       Author = o.Name,
                                                       God = p.Name,
                                                       Name = m.Name,
                                                       Language = n.Name,
                                                       SthotraID = m.SthotraID,
                                                       SthotramData = m.SthotramData,
                                                       NativeName = m.NativeName
                                                   }).ToList();
```

returns an error saying joins not supported

No sure what is different between both queries except the left out join. Please help me find out the issue. Thanks in advance